# Monitoring GPU memory I/O

Tags: memory, nvidia, monitoring, gpu

Is there any way to monitor GPU memory I/O from the shell, with Nvidia graphic cards used with CUDA?

I use `nvidia-smi` to see the current memory utilization, but I would prefer to see the deltas instead (e.g. 10 MB/s), and ideally broken down by processes (as `iotop` does for disk I/O).

`nvidia-smi`:

[image]

`iotop`:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`nvprof` can print nice statistics if you put the appropriate switches. Unfortunately I don't have any example output around, but it can be used like this:

```
nvprof \
    --devices 0 \
    --metrics l1_cache_global_hit_rate \
    --metrics shared_load_transactions \
    ./your_app
```